# Usually the form is POST, but in a single instance it is GET

Tags: cakephp

I do a standard pattern in my application - a link to /controller/delete/object_id, then a post form to "confirm", a check if $this->request->is('post') and if true - the controller deletes the object from database.

What is weird is that for a single, particular object_id, my browser (Firefox) forces the form to be a GET one. With any other object_id everything is ok, but with this particular one, despite all declarations within form tag and etc. brower generates a GET request.

Do you have any clue what this might be?! I even tried to use brower's private mode, because I thought it can be some garbage in browser cache, but the bug is still here.

Comment: can you please show me action code

Comment: View creates the form in a common way:

        echo $this->Form->create('Controller', array('type'=>'post'));
        echo $this->Form->end("delete");

thus creating such a HTML:
<PRE>
<form action="/controller/delete/14" id="ControllerDeleteForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/><div class="submit"><input  type="submit" value="delete"/></div></form>
</pre>

Comment: erm, I must practice this formatting and code pasting. ;-) Anyway, it looks like a browser issue. The only difference in HTML code between pages with form treated as GET and POST are the object_id in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to bypass this problem:

1. define a specific action in form->create, pointing to your controller' method
2. add a hidden field with object_id
3. add some additional code in the controller method to get object_id from $this->request->data, because a hidden post field is not passed as an argument to method, as it is with GET method.

This way, to some unknown reason, it just works. Anyway, I still feel I'm doing something wrong. It's not as "clean" as I would expect.